# Quotient space from $S^2$ such that every point on $S^2 / \sim$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $B_1(0,0)$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S^2=\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\} \subset \Bbb R^3$. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S^2$ such that $(x,y,z) \sim (a,b,c) \iff (x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ or $(x,y,z)=-(a,b,c)$. Show that any point on $S^2/\sim$ has a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to the unit ball $B_1(0,0)$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

So it looks like I have to show that for any $[(x,y,z)] \in S^2/\sim$ I need to find $U$ such that there exists a continuous bijection with continuous inverse $U \to B_1(0,0)$.

How can I do this? I know that $U$ is open in $S^2/  \sim$ if and only if $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S^2$ and here $q:S^2 \to S^2/ \sim$ is the quotient map.

If I define $f:S^2 \to B_1(0,0)$ to be $f(x,y,z)=(x,y)$, then $f$ is a surjection and I think it's also an identification map so this would induce a homeomorphism $f^*:S^2 / \sim \to B_1(0,0)$, but I still don't quite understand the problem. Can I get some hint on this?

Comment: By the way this quotient is an example of a projective space

Comment: Your $f$ does not work, it is not injective. I suggest you visualize what is happening: there is a two dimensional sphere and what you take is an identification of antipodal points, so if you take a very small disc around any point AND its identification (the antipodal disc) you get a disc after the identification.

Comment: Am I squishing the sphere to a plane if I'm identifying all antipodal points? @MathBug

Comment: I think this proof is essentially the same as showing that the projective space is a manifold?

Comment: Not exactly, @SleepWalker . If you divide the sphere into two hemispheres (like the Earth) one hemisphere goes into the other EXCEPT the equator. You have now a hemisphere where the equator has points identified in a certain way, still antipodal. This gives you a projective plane, indeed, and your problem is the same as proving that it is a manifold.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a\in S^2$, let $V=\{b\in S^2\mid\|b-a\|<\sqrt2\}$ (hemisphere, homeomorphic to $B_1(0,0)$), and $U=q(V)$. Then, $U$ is an open neighborhood of $q(a)$ and $q:V\to U$ is a homeomorphism.